# How can I change the height of textOut of TCanvas?

Tags: delphi, textout

I am drawing text on TCanvas using TextOut() but I want bigger fonts.

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this one

```
Canvas.Font.Size := <set your size>;
Canvas.TextOut(0,0,'Sample Text');
```